# Is there any way to find references to types from types outside of the current solution in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio

When right clicking on a type in VisualStudio you can `Find all references` to the selected type in the current solution. Great. But what happens where you're working on a solution that contains low-level or generic libraries on which a number of other solutions depend? How do you find out which external types depend on types in your current working solution?

Is there any other way to reveal dependencies across multiple solutions?

Thanks